# regex with negative lookahead

Tags: regex

I'm trying to parse a line with negative lookahead but I'm having trouble understanding it.

So, if I have a line such as `int a = sincos(a, &a);`

How can I use regex to parse the line above such that it matches all the `a` except the one with `&`?

thanks.

Comment: You're supposed to do a negative lookbehind, not a negative lookahead.

Comment: so would this work ``(?<!&)a``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are actually interested in negative lookbehind here. You want instances of `a` that are not preceded by `&`.

```
\b(?<!&)a\b
```

This pattern looks for instances of `a` that are separated by word boundaries `\b` and are not immediately preceded by an ampersand `(?<!&)`.

Including the word boundaries prevents matching `a` in the middle of other words, otherwise you'd have 5 matches in something like this:

```
var a = calculate(a, &a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://rubular.com/r/cXQSCqWgd2) the kind of thing you're looking for?

Non-capturing group on anything but &, and with a seperate 'a' group

Answer (score 0):

this one would do what you want:

`/(?<!&)a/i`